# as3 control the volume of the microphone with a slider?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

anybody knows how to control the volume of the microphone with a slider ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Microphone object [gain](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Microphone.html#gain) property.

It is used just like volume - singing a value from 0 to 100.

Enjoy.